# How to Change text color based on Access Database values Asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am using a ListView to display a view data items I get from my access data base. This is my code for the list view:

```
<asp:ListView id="ListView2" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3"  EnableViewState="False">
<AlternatingItemTemplate>
    <span style="background-color: white;color: white;">
    Plant Name:
    <asp:Label id="PlantLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Plant") %>' />
    <br />
    Department #:
    <asp:Label id="column1Label" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("column1") %>' />
    <br />
    Department Name:
    <asp:Label id="GroupLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Group") %>' />
    <br />
    Job Code:
    <asp:Label id="Job_CodeLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Job_Code") %>' />
    <br />
    TWA:
    <asp:Label id="TWALabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("TWA") %>' />
    <br />
    Job Classification:
    <asp:Label id="Job_ClassificationLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Job_Classification") %>' />
    <br />
    Job Function:
    <asp:Label id="Job_FunctionLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Job_Function") %>' />
    <br />
    Job Description:
    <asp:Label id="Job_DescriptionLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Job_Description") %>' />
```

I am to be able to when TWA values are >= 85 and <90 the text turns yellow, when its >=90 it turns red, and when its < 85 it should be green. How exactly would i do this. I am using Javascript, html, asp.net (C#). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please take some time to format your code.

Answer (score 0):

I would setup a style first for the two colors you want then just implement the following in a `OnDataBinding` event that you could re-use for other labels if necessary:

```
<asp:Label id="TWALabel" runat="server" OnDataBinding="YourLabel_DataBinding" />
```

Then in your C# code:

```
protected void YourLabel_DataBinding(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Label lbl = (Label)(sender);
    int TWA = (int)(Eval("TWA"));
    lbl.Text = TWA.ToString();
    if (TWA >= 85)
    {
        if (TWA < 90)
        {
            lbl.CssClass = "yourYellowClass";
        }
        else
        {
            lbl.CssClass = "yourRedClass";
        }
    }
    // else do nothing since below 85 just have the default as green (eg. yourGreenClass)...
}
```

Comment: Do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: @mateen esfahanian Do you understand how the code works?  It should work if you made the classes and included them properly and adjusted you code. Error?  Also not sure why you have a `span` with white on white in your template.

Comment: <style>           .YellowThis            {
             background-color:yellow;
 
} 
</style>
<style>
.RedThis
{
 background-color:red;
}
</style>
<style>
.GreenThis            
{
 background-color:green;
}
</style>
           protected void YourLabel_DataBinding(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Label lbl = (Label)(sender);
    int TWA = (int)(Eval("TWA"));
    lbl.Text = TWA.ToString();
    if (TWA >= 85)
    {
        if (TWA < 90)
        {
 lbl.CssClass = "YellowThis";
        }
        else
 {
lbl.CssClass = "RedThis";
 }}
 else 
  {
 lbl.CssClass="GreenThis";
 }}

Comment: @mateen esfahanian Adding the code doesn't help me help you... do you understand how it works?  Have you tried to trace it?  Does the `OnDataBinding` event fire?  There is a lot you can do to help yourself...

Comment: @ Kelsey It seems to me when I add OnDataBinding="YourLabel_DataBinding" to the <asp:label id=TWALabel> line, it causes the data not to fire. When I remove that line, I am back to normal with the data firing just not color coated. So I think its a problem with my data, am I correct?

Comment: @mateen esfahanian Try switching your `ListView` to a `Repeater` and make sure you are calling the DataBind() on the `Repeater.  It looks like your using a lot of the built in stuff which I rarely use.  I find it easier to assign the datasource manually and bind it as needed etc.  Much easier to keep track of what is going on.

Comment: I don't want to mess with the Repeater function really, I don't to get more confused